# Why is the compiler stating that I am applying to many arguments?

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml

For this function I am given two ints and I am supposed to place the range of numbers from num1 to num2 into a list.

```
let rec range num1 num2 =
  (* YOUR CODE HERE *)
  if num2 < num1 then raise IncorrectRange
  else if num1 = num2 then [num1]
  else let num3 = num1 +1 in num1::(range num3 num2)

let range() = assert (range 2 5 = [2;3;4;5])
```

For some reason when I test my code it states that the function is type unit -> unit and that it is applied too too many arguments. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you've posted compiles fine. The error must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your code consists of two definitions of a function named `range`, with different types. This is legitimate OCaml code (the second definition hides the first one), but this seems very unlikely to be what is intended.

My guess is that there's a typo in the `assert` line.

At any rate, any code that you enter after this will be using the second definition of `range`, which indeed has the type `unit -> unit`.